# Long pressed UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton

I was wondering if I could capture an event (via Notification or some other mechanism), of a UIButton if somebody is holding the key pressing a UIButton for an excessive period of time; longer than a single button push - let's say somebody that holds the button pressed for a few seconds...

Thank you.

Comment: lol. yeah, up arrow all answers that were helpful or correct, and put a checkmark next to that one, best answer that came closest or was most constructive. Go ahead and repeat this process for all of your old questions for which people successfully solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add [`UILongPressGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILongPressGestureRecognizer) to your button, pass a selector in its `initWithTarget:action:`, and choose the duration time by setting its `minimumPressDuration` property.